# R- Incorrect number of dimension

Tags: r, dimension

Here's my code:

```
#Data initialisation

data <- is.data.frame(resultats15)
genotype <- data$genotype
aire <- data$aire

#ANOVA et Tukey test

library(TukeyC)
resaov <- aov(aire~genotype)
anova(resaov)

TukeyC(resaov)

library(multcompView)
multcompBoxplot(aire~genotype, data, horizontal = FALSE)

#Error in data[, fm[-1]] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Previously, i tried something like this:

```
#Data initialisation

data <- resultats15
genotype <- data$genotype
aire <- data$aire

#ANOVA et Tukey test

library(TukeyC)
resaov <- aov(aire~genotype)
anova(resaov)

TukeyC(resaov)

library(multcompView)
multcompBoxplot(aire~genotype, data, horizontal = FALSE)

#Error in tapply(data[, fm[2]], data[, fm[3]], function(x) do.call(sortFn,  : 
arguments must have same length

length(aire)
#1600
length(genotype)
#1600
```

I would like to obtain boxplots with multi comparisons using TukeyHSD method. 
I don't understand this problem of "number of dimensions" can you help me?

Comment: In the first line of your code, it looks like you want to convert `resulats15` to a data frame. If so, do `data = as.data.frame(resultats15)`. `is.data.frame` is a logical function to test whether an object is a data frame. `is.data.frame` returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`.